# How do I SILENTLY create external user under enterprise account? No invite

Tags: box-api

Is there a way to create an external user account under an enterprise account silently, where there is no accept/email invite needed?

Use Case:
User becomes a member of our web site, we call API and provision grant them silently which creates an external user under our enterprise account.

Any code axample?  Silently and without invite is the key thing here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this. The user doesn't have a password at creation time and needs to set one by going to the website via the email confirmation link.

Could you perhaps explain why you don't want the email to be sent, and what your user workflow  looks like?